# DrawerLayoutAndroid don't show menu with openDrawer method

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I would like use `DrawerLayoutAndroid` module on React-Native app. For use `openDrawer` programmaticaly, i use `useRef` hook.

On run this method, my Drawer show only black "overflow", but not the navigation.

If i swip to the right, my Drawler menu will be show :/

My code :

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  let drawler = useRef(null);

  return (
    <DrawerLayoutAndroid
      drawerWidth={300}
      drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
      ref={drawler}
      renderNavigationView={() => (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left' }}>
            I'm in the Drawer!
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={() => drawler.current.openDrawer()}> // Show only overflow, not the menu
              Open drawler
            </Button>
            {children}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
  );
};
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with useCallback

```
const [drawer, setDrawer] = useState();
const refDrawer = useCallback(element => {
    setDrawer(element);
}, []);
```

Don't forget set `ref={refDrawer}` attribute to the DrawerLayoutAndroid component.